# hadoop container stdout is always empty

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Why is stdout file of a job container in hadoop is always of size 0.

On java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
static final Logger MAPLOGGER= Logger.getLogger(MyMap.class.getName());
MAPLOGGER.warn("key is :"+key);
```

after running jar, 3 files are generated

stderr, stdout,syslog

stderr contains

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger   (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

where exactly `MAPLOGGER.warn("key is :"+key);` writes the log?.

Comment: It writes to the task's log file. `stdout` like the name says, is for the standard output like `System.out.print`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks, any pointers how to fix this.

Comment: There is nothing to fix, this is the desired behaviour.

Comment: so, why the stdout file is always empty.  I want to write logs for debugging map class.

Comment: Because you are writing to the LOG not to the stdout.

Comment: Thomas means that you should check the task logs, not the file you are trying to write to.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't write it anywhere right now, because you have not set up log4j.

From the link in the WARN message:

"Why do I see a warning about "No appenders found for logger" and "Please configure log4j properly"?
This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration. log4j uses Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource() to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place log4j.properties or log4j.xml requires understanding the search strategy of the class loader in use. log4j does not provide a default configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be prohibited in some environments."

So you need to set up the log4j engine, and give it to Java overall, or explicitly declare their location in the application.

Comment: could you please be precise on which file/location I need to set log4j?. Do I need to set the classpath in yarn-site.xml?

Comment: I can't, because I do not know where it is in your system. You should read the information on the link in the message.